# NiFi fails to start after setting sensitive parameter into non-sensitive property

Tags: apache-nifi

My NiFi begins to start-up and after some time (before GUI comes on-line) it shuts down. In log appeares message like this one:
`org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... The property cannot reference Parameter because Sensitive Parameters may only be referenced by Sensitive Properties.`

Please, what I should do to be able to start NiFi and solve this?

Answer (score 2):

To start NiFi with such mis-setup it is necessary to remove conflicting setting from flow. To do so:

1. Backup your original flow - file `<nifi-home>/conf/flow.xml.gz`
2. Extract file `flow.xml` from this archive
3. Find problematic xml element using names referenced in error message and remove the offending value-line. So this:

```
    <entry>
      <key>Password</key>
      <value>#{ftp_password}</value>
    </entry>
```

becomes this:

```
    <entry>
      <key>Password</key>
    </entry>
```

4. Repack archive and start NiFi - now it should come online
5. This time set your sensitive values in a correct way :-)